# Calculation of Unit vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

If I have a vector 5$\vec{u}$, what should be the expression for its unit vector?

Should it be:

1. 5$\vec{u}\frac{1}{5||\vec{u}||}$ ? OR
2. $\vec{u}\frac{5}{||\vec{u}||}$

And why?

I understand that that for a vector $\vec{u}$, its unit vector expression would be $\vec{u}\frac{1}{||\vec{u}||}$

Comment: So it's the first choice, since the 5's cancel. Choice $2$ has length 5, because it is 5 times $\frac{u}{|u|}$, and $\frac{u}{|u|}$ is a unit vector.

Comment: @nick So anyway, it is always $\frac{u}{|u|}$? since the coefficient always cancels

Comment: Correct. Another way to think about it is to call $v = 5u$. Then the unit vector in this direction is $\frac{v}{|v|} = \frac{5u}{|5u|} = \frac{5u}{5|u|} = \frac{u}{|u|}$.

Comment: Okay thank you for the suggestion! This way of thinking is way easier !

Answer (score 0):

In general, the unit vector in the direction of any vector $\vec{v}\neq\vec{0}$ is  just $\vec{v}/||\vec{v}||$, since this vector obviously has the same direction (being multiplied by only a positive scalar factor), and also has unit length. Therefore as suggested in the comments, the unit vector in the direction of $5\vec{u}$ will be simply
$$\frac{5\vec{u}}{||5\vec{u}||},$$
which is your first option. Note also that since $5\vec{u}$ is obviously in the same direction as $\vec{u}$, the unit vector must remain the same, so this gives us another way to see that the answer must be equivalent to $\vec{u}/||u||$, which is satisfied by the first option, since the scalar factor of $5$ in the numerator and denominator cancel.